# Как мне использовать callback_query: types.CallbackQuery и message: types.Message в одной функции?

Tags: python, aiogram

Или как мне корректно вывести сообщение ?

```
from aiogram.types.message import ContentType
from aiogram import types

from loader import bot, dp
from data import config

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('buy '))
async def buy_callback_run(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    
    PRICE = types.LabeledPrice(label=f"Покупка {callback_query.data.replace('buy ', '')}", amount=800*100)
    # buy_message(PRICE, callback_query)
    # if config.PAYMENTS_TOKEN.split(':')[1] == 'TEST':
    #     await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Купить')
    # async def buy_message(message: types.Message):    
    await bot.send_invoice(message.chat.id,
                        title=f"Покупка {callback_query.data.replace('buy ', '')}",
                        description=callback_query.data.replace('buy ', ''),
                        provider_token=config.PAYMENTS_TOKEN,
                        currency='rub',
                        photo_url="url",
                        photo_width=416,
                        photo_height=234,
                        photo_size=416,
                        is_flexible=False,
                        prices=[PRICE],
                        start_parameter='one-month-subscription',
                        payload='test-invoice-payload')
    
    
@dp.pre_checkout_query_handler(lambda query: True)
async def pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q: types.PreCheckoutQuery):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q.id, ok = True)
    
    
@dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
async def successful_payment(message: types.Message):
    print('SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT:')
    payment_info = message.successful_payment.to_python()
    for k, v in payment_info.items():
        print(f'{k} = {v}')
        
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Платеж на сумму - {message.successful_payment.total_amount // 100} {message.successful_payment.currency} прошел успешно!')
```

Сам "buy" формируется так

```
async def sql_read(message):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host=config.HOST, 
    user=config.USER,  
    password=config.PASSWORD, 
    database=config.DB_NAME,
    )
    connection.autocommit = True
    
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM menu;")
        for ret in cursor.fetchall():
            await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена: {ret[-1]} рублей')
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='^^^', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup()\
                .add(InlineKeyboardButton(f'Купить {ret[1]}', callback_data=f'buy {ret[1]}')))
            
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно, я решил эту ситуацию изменив

```
message.chat.id
```

на

```
callback_query.message.chat.id
```